# How many days travel is it from Shadowdale to Myth Drannor?

Tags: forgotten-realms, travel

The group is headed back to Shadowdale after there little mission.
How many days travel would it be to get from Myth Drannor to Shadowdale?

Comment: What game are you playing? Some edition of D&D (since I think those are FR places)? Which edition (since travel rules differ)?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed, don't worry, when we know what you are asking, eg. you specify the edition and party composition (mounts, any characters that slow you down?), then we will reopen it.

Comment: Route also factors, as there isn’t a road to default to.